# Is there any Sanskrit and English version of Critical Edition of Mahabharat available?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, vyasa, book-recommendation, translation

Sanskrit and English version of NeelKath edition of Mahabharat is [available online.](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/itihaas/mahabharat)
Sanskrit and Hindi NeelKanth edition is of Gita Press.(Gita Press has removed many verses)

Is sanksrit & English (or Even Hindi) version of Critical edition of Mahabharat available anywhere ?
[Only Sanskrit](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html) version is available.
Only English Version is also available. Its by Bibek Debroy.
But I couldn't find both these combined in one.
The one by Satvalekar (Sanskrit and Hindi) is available on archive but it has many skipped pages.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links.:

- [BORI Mahabharata in Sanskrit along with Hindi Translations by Pundit S.D. Satawlekar Ji :- Complete Volumes.](https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata04SanskritHindiPanditRamnarayanGitaPress)
- [English translations by Kisari Mohan Ganguli Ji. Downloadable File along with online reading.](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharataOfKrishna-dwaipayanaVyasa)
- [BORI Mahabharata - English translations by Bibek Debroy Sir:- The Mahabharata (Version 2) : Veda Vyāsa : Free Download & Streaming.](https://archive.org/details/TheMahabharata_201707)
- M.N Dutt Translation in English.:

• [Adi Parva to Udyoga Parva.](https://archive.org/details/aproseenglishtr00duttgoog)

• [Bhishma to Stri Parva.](https://archive.org/details/aproseenglishtr01duttgoog)

• [Shanti Parva.](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.142208)

• [Anushashana to Swargarohana Parva.](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.142210)

- BORI CE Mahabharata – Vishnu Sitaram Sukthankar.:

• [Online Reading.](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html)

• [Downloadable Files.](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367546)

- [Mahabharata 04 - Sanskrit-Hindi Translation by Pandit Ramnarayan Dutt Shastri Pandey From Gita Press.](https://www.scribd.com/doc/101858555/Mahabharata-04-Sanskrit-Hindi-translation-by-Pandit-Ramnarayan-Dutt-Shastri-Pandey-from-Gita-Press)

Credit.: Mr. Deepak Kumar Jha.

I hope this helps.